# HTTP Errors handling in Angular

Tags: angular, http

I need to inform the user if the POST, GET or PUT method was correctly performed.
Is there a good way to do that.

For example POST method in component for sending data:

```
SendData() {
    this.srv.PostData(this.user).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log('Success', data);
      },
      error => console.log('Error', error)
    );
  }
```

In Http service I have:

```
PostData(userdata: User) {
    return this.http.post<any>(this.url + this.postDataString, userdata);
  }
```

What I wish to have is:
- get information that the POST or PUT is performed (how to get informed about 200 OK or other HTTP answer?)
- get information that GET method is performed correctly (how to get informed about 404 Not Found or other HTTP error code?)

Thank you for any answer.

Regards

EDIT:
What I added is:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
    HttpEvent,
    HttpInterceptor,
    HttpHandler,
    HttpRequest,
    HttpErrorResponse,
    HttpResponse
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError, switchMap, filter, take, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
//import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
@Injectable()
export class HttpErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(error => {

            if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && (error.status === 401)) {
                sessionStorage.setItem('accessToken', '');
            } else if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && (error.status === 500 )) {
               console.log('500 Internal Server Error', '', { timeOut: 5000 });
                return throwError(error);
            } else if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && (error.status === 502 )) {
               console.log('502 Bad Gateway', '', { timeOut: 5000 });
                return throwError(error);
            } else if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && (error.status === 503 )) {
               console.log('503 Service Unavailable', '', { timeOut: 5000 });
                return throwError(error);
            } else if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && (error.status === 504 )) {
               console.log('504 Gateway Timeout', '', { timeOut: 5000 });
                return throwError(error);
            } else if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && (error.status === 0 )) {
               console.log('503 Service Temporarily Unavailable', '', { timeOut: 5000 });
                return throwError(error);
            } else if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && (error.status === 200 )) {
                console.log('200 OK', '', { timeOut: 5000 });
                 return throwError(error);
            } else  {
                return throwError(error);
            }
        }),
        tap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
            if (event instanceof HttpResponse && event.status === 200) {
              console.log('SUCCESS - 200');
            }
          })
        );
    }
}
```

Now the question is, how can I invoke and give proper message regarding the method I am calling like: 
- GET data for User 
- Get data for Manager
- etc.
?

So the question is how can I know which HTTP method and URL is in use right now?

Another Question:
I need to send a user a snackbar or alert if anything is wrong. What is your recommendation for such function? Where should I call it?

Comment: Using intercepter you can handle http errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create intercepter 
   `http.intercepter.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
    HttpEvent,
    HttpInterceptor,
    HttpHandler,
    HttpRequest,
    HttpErrorResponse
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, switchMap, filter, take } from 'rxjs/operators';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
@Injectable()
export class HttpErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(error => {
            if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && (error.status === 401)) {
            } else if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && (error.status === 500 )) {
               console.log('500 Internal Server Error');
                return throwError(error);
            } else if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && (error.status === 502 )) {
               console.log('502 Bad Gateway');
                return throwError(error);
            } else if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && (error.status === 503 )) {
               console.log('503 Service Unavailable');
                return throwError(error);
            } else if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && (error.status === 504 )) {
               console.log('504 Gateway Timeout');
                return throwError(error);
            } else if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && (error.status === 0 )) {
               console.log('503 Service Temporarily Unavailable');
                return throwError(error);
            } else  {
                return throwError(error);
            }
        }));
    }
}
```

And inject it into app module like this.

```
import { HttpErrorInterceptor } from './core/http.intercepter';
providers: [{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: HttpErrorInterceptor, multi: true }]
```

Comment: And that is all?

Comment: It will work for all http request globally, when any request fail it will log corrosponding  error.

Comment: That is what I needed.

Comment: I added the code with: ``` tap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
            if (event instanceof HttpResponse && event.status === 200) {
              //this.toastr.success("Object created.");
              console.log('SUKCES - 200');
            }
          })``` Can I get to every 200 OK answer and inform the user regarding where it was intercepted?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Interceptor](https://blog.angulartraining.com/http-interceptors-in-angular-61dcf80b6bdd),

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
       tap(event => {
         if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
            console.log('succeed');
         }
        },err => {
           console.log(`Error code ${err.status}, body : ${err.error}`);
       }
    ))
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **Interceptor** for global

Here is [example for you](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-interceptor-error-handle-wqzik8?file=app/app.component.ts)

```
 handleErrorM = (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    console.log('Handle on Component', error);

    if (error.status === 401) {
      this.showError = true;
      this.error = error.message;
      return Observable.of(error.message);

    }
    this.showError = true;
    this.error = error.message;
    return Observable.of(error.message);
  };
```